# How to change color of different rows in datagrid c# windows ce

Tags: c#, graphics, datagrid, compact-framework, windows-ce

I try to develop a c# application(gathering products by their barcodes) to windows ce handheld device with compact framework 3.5

I have a datagrid and datagrid is bind with a datatable by sql. There are 4 columns in my datagrid, 3rd column represents the quantity of the products needs to be collected, and last column comes with the default value 0(quantity collected). Whenever user enters a product code, quantity of the product increases 1 by 1.

I want to make background color of the row blue when user enters corresponding product code(to show which product is being collected)

and also I want to make background color green if user collects the needed products.

I tried coloring row by selected index but it does not work. When selection gone , colours are gone.

Here is a picture of screen when needed quantity of product was collected.[image]

Here is when I want to see the processed row.
[image]

Below is my code of the keypress event of the textbox(entering of product code)

```
        private void txtUrunkod_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in dt.Columns) col.ReadOnly = false; 
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            islemkod = txtUrunkod.Text;
            islemkod.Trim();

            if (islemkod.Contains('/'))
            { 
                serikodbol = islemkod.Split('/');
                urunKodum = serikodbol[0];
                DataRow row = dt.Select("urunkodu='" + urunKodum + "'").FirstOrDefault();
                int guncelle = Convert.ToInt32(row[3]);
                guncelle++;
                row[3] = guncelle;
            }
            else if (islemkod.Length == 8)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec MY_TOPUK_BILGI_GETIR '" + islemkod + "'", conStr);
                conStr.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                uk = new DataTable();
                uk.Load(dr);
                conStr.Close();
                //toplamaGrid.Select(0);
                foreach (DataRow row2 in uk.Rows)
                {
                    urunKodum = row2[0].ToString();
                }
                DataRow row = dt.Select("urunkodu='" + urunKodum + "'").FirstOrDefault();
                int guncelle = Convert.ToInt32(row[3]);
                guncelle++;
                row[3] = guncelle;
                int index = -1;
                bool found = false;

                foreach (DataRow datr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    index++;
                    string d = datr["urunkodu"].ToString();
                    if (datr[0].ToString() == urunKodum)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }


                if (found && !row[2].Equals(row[3]))
                {

                    toplamaGrid.Select(index);
                    toplamaGrid.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
                }
                else if (row[2].Equals(row[3]))
                {
                    toplamaGrid.Select(index);
                    toplamaGrid.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
                    //toplamaGrid.UnSelect(index);
                }



            }

            else if (islemkod.Length == 7 && islemkod[0] == 'P')
            {

            }

            else//islemkod.Length != 8 && !islemkod.Contains('/')
            {//
                urunKodum = txtUrunkod.Text;
                txtUrunkod.Visible = false;
                lblurunkod.Visible = false;
                txtifAdres.Visible = true;
                lbladressor.Visible = true;
                txtifAdres.Focus();

            }
            updated = true;
            txtUrunkod.Text = "";
            sonindex = 0;
        }
    }
```

I couldnt find many info about this. Any help will be important. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408113/changing-row-colors-in-the-compact-framework-datagrid?rq=1. You need to implement custom drawing in Paint event.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I experienced the same problem. Make use of ***DataGridFormatCellEventArgs*** for coloring the solution.

[explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908705/color-whole-row-instead-of-single-cell?noredirect=1&lq=1) Add the DataGrid file to your code in the link. (***DataGridFormatCellEventArgs.cs and FormattableTextBoxColumn.cs***) These files contain the Paint class that was used to do the coloring.

[different example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673397/change-datagrid-selected-row-colour-after-paint)

I hope I could help. If you experience difficulties, I can give an example from my own code.